# how to split a bitstream with ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, h.265

I am trying to split with ffmpeg a bitstream whose extension is .hevc which is generated by the platform HM 16.11 in several segments according to the GOP
I want to have several files whose extension is .hevc each file contains a single GOP
i found this command line 'segmentmuxer' but there is the extension is not adapted it is .mkv and my file is .hevc

```
ffmpeg -i in.mkv -codec copy -map 0 -f segment -segment_list out.csv - segment_frames 100,200,300,500,800 out%03d.nut
```

can anyone help me
thank you

Answer (score 1):

Raw bitstreams don't have timestamps so the segment muxer will not work the file as it is. You have to mux it to a container with timestamps.

So step 1 is

```
ffmpeg -i in.hevc -codec copy in.mp4
```

or

```
mp4box -add in.hevc -new in.mp4
```

and then, step 2 is

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -map 0 -f segment -segment_list out.csv -segment_time 0.01 out%03d.nut
```